# Please explain? Typescript index signature

Tags: typescript, properties, typescript-typings

I've just stumbled across the following syntax in TypeScript

```
export interface OrderPool {
    [id: string]: Level3Order;
}
```

Could someone clarify what I am looking at?

Best I can understand is that this is an interface `OrderPool` which contains a property named Id of type `string(array?)` and something of type `Level3Order`????

What is the relationship of `Level3Order` to the property Id and is Id an array or single instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that means Objects that implement the interface OrderPool contain key/value pairs, where the key (called id in this case) is of type string and the value is of type Level3Order

for example this objects correctly implements the interface:

```
{
  'item1': new Level3Order,
  'anotherItem': new Level3Order
}
```

You could also have something like

```
export interface OrderPool {
  [id: number]: Level3Order;
}
```

example:

```
{
  1: new Level3Order(),
  5: new Level3Order()
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, This answer most clearly explains my question.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is simply, "If you index into something of type *OrderPool*, you get back something of type *Level3Order*."

The type of the signature should always be *string or number*. The name of the parameter ("id") is immaterial.

Take a look at the example below to get a complete idea.

```
class Level3Order{
    public dummy : number = 0;
}

export interface OrderPool {
    [id :string]: Level3Order;
}

let pool : OrderPool ={}
pool["test"] = 5; //Error number is not assignable to Level3Order
pool["test"] = new Level3Order();  //Ok
pool["whatever"] = new Level3Order();  //Ok
pool.whatever =  new Level3Order(); //Still ok
pool["test"].dummy = 5; // Dummy is a property on Level3Order, Ok
```